# plot in matlab with constraints in the variables

Tags: matlab

I wanted to plot a function of the form

`f(p,q)=0`

in the region `0 < p < 1, 0 < q < 1-p`. I used `ezplot`:

```
ezplot('f(p,q)',[0,1])
```

is what I could do. But it looks uglier because the function is well defined only in the triangular region `0 < p < 1, 0 < q < 1-p`. So beyond this region, I think, it just plots the real/imaginary part of the function, and hence the uglier. But I would like to draw only in the triangular region `0 < p < 1, 0 < q < 1-p`.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could go about pulling out the values that you want to plot.  This is by no means a copy paste answer for what you're do though.

```
p = -1:.1:2; % Just giving p some random values so that we can pull 0 < p < 1 from it.
ind = intersect(find(p>0), find(p<1)); % This returns the intersection of the two sets from p.  Not really the best way, but it's a concise one-liner.

% Now to pull the values from p.
p_values = p(ind); % That simple!  This is because ind has the actual indexes where p < 1 and p > 0.
```

In all honesty this probably isn't the best way to get the information out of p, but it's just what came off the top of my head before I get my coffee going.

As far as pulling the information for q, you can follow a similar manner just making sure that you keep within the constraints that you have set for it.

Remember when it comes to plotting that you'll need to have vectors of the same length, but if you index of the `p_values` to get you `q_values` you should be good there.

Hope that gets you somewhat of a start and on the right path.

Comment: The function I have, f(p,q)=0 can not be easily solved for q. So, it would be very difficult to find q_values. I never thought the problem was that hard.

Comment: It might help to post up the actual function/code so people can take a look at what the actual data is like and lend more of a hand.